# jQuery ajax call race condition?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following javascript function:

```
function deploy() {
    $.ajax({
        url: '/Theme/Deploy',
        type: 'POST'
    });
    location.reload();
}
```

This function is called when a button is clicked.  I want to kick off the server call then immediately refresh the page.  When I use the code above, it never makes the server call, it only refreshes the page.  When I remove the `location.reload()` call, it makes the call successfully.

Is there a race condition or something happening where it reloads the page before the ajax call even though it's below it in code?

Comment: what are you trying to do? Infinite requests???

Comment: Forget about using Ajax. Rewrite it so that `/Theme/Deploy`  redirects back to the page you want to view. Submit the data to it with a regular form submission.

Comment: @Vishwanath: `deploy()` is called on button click not page load.

Comment: @Quentin: That would mean my async code would be on the server.

Answer (score 3):

The request is asynchronous. This means that the `reload()` is called *before* the request has completed.

To achieve what you require you should place the `location.reload()` inside the `success` handler of the AJAX call so it runs *after* the request completes:

```
function deploy() {
    $.ajax({
        url: '/Theme/Deploy',
        type: 'POST',
        success: function() {
            location.reload();
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: I don't want to wait until the request completes.  Hence the usage of the phrases `immediately` and `kick off`.

Comment: I'm afraid you can't do that. As you've discovered if the request is too slow then it will be cancelled due to the new request called from `reload()` before the AJAX completes

Comment: You can't simply make the request?  I don't care if the current browser's request is cancelled.  Once it hits the server, it will start running the server code.  Isn't that the point of a asynchronous call?  That you don't need to wait for the response.

Comment: You need to still be on the same page when the request completes. Hence my usage of the phrase `you can't do that` ;)

Comment: If I just had the ajax call in my `deploy()` function, called it via the button click, and then hit F5, the server call is kicked off and continues to run.  Why is replacing the page refresh programmatically with the `location.reload()` call not allowed?

Comment: @im1dermike When you do it manually, what you're seeing is the AJAX request completing before you can hit F5 to refresh the page. When you call `location.reload()`, all network requests (including AJAX) are stopped and the page is loaded from scratch. This is why Rory is saying that you can't do that, because browsers don't work that way. You can't have an AJAX request that persists between page loads.

Answer (score 0):

Try calling the server as a script tag. I am not sure if this will work for sure, but in my tests it seemed to work making parallel requests.

```
function deploy(){
    var head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
    var sc = document.createElement('script');
    sc.setAttribute('src', '/Theme/Deploy');
    head.appendChild(sc);
    location.reload();
}
```